# Deploy to Digital Ocean Droplet from travis

Tags: docker, travis-ci, digital-ocean

I have a web app running in a docker container. I am able to run tests and create build when code is merged into master branch in travis. I need to deploy the build to digital ocean droplet, but cannot find any documentation or sources on how this could be achieved.

I am able to find documentation on how this can be deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and S3 but cannot find anything for digital ocean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configure your code repo, such as Github, to post to a webhook exposed by your CICD server, in your case Travis, (in my Jenkins). And it is Travis which should push the built image to the Docker registry, presumably an internal repo at D.O. (Docker Hub or Red Hat Container Registry in my case), where the image change would trigger a new application deployment (to staging only in my case).